# How to automatically place AutoText in Word styles?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, styles

I am making a screenplay in Microsoft Office Word 2007, and created various styles to quickly make formatting changes for the various aspects of the screenplay. My character style, for example, appears at the beginning of each line of dialogue in the script, naming the character who will then speak his/her lines.

I would like to insert a number at the beginning of each character line, so that during rehearsals and such, I can call out which line to start from. I don't want to use a list because it indents strangely, and would like to use autotext. In addition, I would like each numbering system to restart at the beginning of each section (scene), to make the dialogue easier. I have never used VBA in Word, but i have some programming skills in Java. How would I accomplish this?

EDIT: I figured it out by using the numbering in the styles, then adjusting the tabs.

Comment: Welcome at superuser. Please edit your post and clarify what is your question, it's too broad now. (this isn't a free code writing service, you likely to get answer only for specific questions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the standard Word functionality:

[image]

The screenshot is in German interface. In English, I think, it is named "Page Layout"->"Line Numbers". In the options (the last menu item) it is possible to reset the numbering on each section.